# get file system shares working with virt-manager 1.3.2 in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, virt-manager

I have tried numerous things, and read numerous articles, but I'm not able to get file-system shares to work. Here is my setup:

- host machine:

  - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with KVM and virt-manager 1.3.2 installed
  - folder being shared is `/stuff` as `share`
  - `/stuff` has `g+s` set
  - group owner of `/stuff` is `stuff-group`
  - `libvirt-qemu` is a member of `stuff-group`
  - virt-manager driver for filesystem share is default
  - virt-manager mode for filesystem share is passthrough
  - when logged into host as `libvirt-qemu` `libvirt-qemu` can create files in `/stuff`
- guest machine is Ubuntu 16.04 Server

  - `share` is mounted to `/files`
  - I can see the file/folders from the host's `/stuff` but I cannot create new files

If it matters, `/stuff` will be mounted on guest and used for ownCloud's data directory so the guest's `www-data` and `owncloud` users will be creating files in it.

Comment: Did you try 'Mapped' for the Mode?

Comment: @garethTheRed: It works in mapped mode but I was hoping the host would show permissions from the guest. Both the host and guest have a user with UID 1234 so if the user creates a file in the guest it should show the same user owns it on the host.